# Django easy way to create model from a multiple models

Tags: django, python-2.7

Given these pseudo-models:

```
class A(models.Model):
    aa = models.CharField()
    ab = models.CharField()
    # ... many other fields

class B(models.Model):
    ba = models.CharField()
    bb = models.CharField()
    # ... many other fields

class C(models.Model):
    ca = models.CharField()
    cb = models.CharField()
    # ... many other fields
```

Now I have another model which aggregates **SOME** of the above models' properties, like this, think of it as an audit table which stores snapshots:

```
class Agg(models.Model):
    aa = models.CharField() # from A
    bb = models.CharField() # from B
    ca = models.CharField() # from C
    # ... many other fields from A, B and C
```

When creating an `Agg` I need to name all of the properties explicitly like the following:

```
Agg.objects.create(
         aa=a_instance.aa, 
         bb=b_instance.bb, 
         ca=c_instance.ca, # and so on ...
)
```

This is cumbersome if models have many fields. Is there a better/shorter way of doing this?

Comment: I can't think of an easy "out of the box" way to do this. If I were you, I'd write a custom function `take_snapshot(a, b ,c)` or something and unit test it (so your updates won't be cumbersome). In other words, don't write `Agg.objects.create...` directly in your views or forms. If you don't want to repeat your fields, catavaran solution is good.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `Meta.get_all_field_names()` method to get the list of `Avg` fields and then copy fields with the same names from `A`, `B` or `C` instance:

```
def create_avg(*args):
    data = {}
    for field_name in Avg._meta.get_all_field_names():
        if field_name != 'id':
            for instance in args:
                if hasattr(instance, field_name):
                    data[field_name] = getattr(instance, field_name)
                    break
    Avg.objects.create(**data)
```

And then call this function as:

```
avg_instance = create_avg(a_instance, b_instance, c_instance)
```

This solutions doesn't handle `ManyToMany` fields but can be easily modified to do so.